# dict of internal keys

Tags: python, dictionary, key-value

I'd like to include groups of internal values within a dict.  Example:

```
# Given
>>> d = {'apple': 'red',
...      'orange': 'orange',
...      'lemon': 'yellow',
...      'milk': 'white',
...      'coffee': 'brown',
...     }

# Grouped key
>>>d = {'apple': 'red',
...     'orange': 'orange',
...     'lemon': 'yellow',
...     'milk': 'white',
...     'coffee': 'brown',
...     'fruits': [d['apple'], d['orange'], d['lemon']],   # group
...    }

# Desired result
>>> d['fruits] 
['apple','orange','lemon']
```

Is there a pythonic way to build a dict such that values can reference existing keys?

Comment: I assume you mean that you want them to reference the current values, even if they're changed in the outer dict?

Comment: I hadn't thought about the dict changing, but ideally yes.  If i add more fruits to the d, i'd like to access the group rather than calling each fruit separately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value key pairs must exist before you reference them. You can add the 'fruits' value after building the dictionary like this:

```
d = {'apple': 'red',
'orange': 'orange',
'lemon': 'yellow',
'milk': 'white',
'coffee': 'brown'}

d['fruits'] = [d['apple'], d['orange'], d['lemon']] 

print d['fruits']
```

I'm not sure if you really wanted to output the fruits and not their associated color though, this will output:

```
['red', 'orange', 'yellow']
```

If you change any of the fruits values though, (for example 'red' to 'green') this will not automatically update the value in the 'fruits' list, in case you wanted that.